# Chrome-Extension | Google Maps cannot be scripted due to an ExtensionsSettings policy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject a content script into google-maps page using the below code for extracting some info

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id, allFrames: false },
        files: ['page.js'],
    }).then(() => {
        // Doing some stuff
    });
});
```

For example this URL: https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/117085129581545773137/reviews/@40.490946,-75.2538051,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m3!8m2!3m1!1e1

always getting this error message: **Uncaught (in promise) Error: This page cannot be scripted due to an ExtensionsSettings policy.**

manifest.json file

```
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Click to view a popup",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "storage",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon16-999.png",
        "48": "images/icon48-999.png",
        "128": "images/icon128-999.png"
    }
}
```

However other sites it's working fine.

Comment: The error message means that the domain admin has disabled extensions on this site.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ok, but for example, this published extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/seo-minion/giihipjfimkajhlcilipnjeohabimjhi/related?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon
is working fine on google maps, and for sure it uses content-script for extracting data.
the only difference that I can see is that my extension is unpacked.
Do you think this makes difference?

Comment: The domain admin has allowed known extensions.

Comment: I guess so. Thanks